# How to use Projection_traits_xy_3?

Tags: cgal

I can only see the projection trait used in Delaunay examples. And it looks simple enough.

I'm trying to use it in the following code and I couldn't figure it out!

I might be doing something right because Polygon_2::push_back now expects a Point_3.

But the rest spits out pages of error messages.

Any idea?

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Boolean_set_operations_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Projection_traits_xy_3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#include "print_utils.h"

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel  Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<Kernel>                 Gt;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<Gt>                                  Polygon_2;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_with_holes_2<Gt>                       Polygon_with_holes_2;
typedef Gt::Point_2                                          Point_3;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Point_3 rp(1.840203021427314, 11.442402094914751, 1.6289004237251579);
  Point_3 rq(-1.3754475586433301, 7.159592255512721, -0.8694054147780097);
  Point_3 rr(5.879661577210586, 9.559327916542575, 0.530440182558408);

  Point_3 aa(6.11, 18.550001, 5.775);
  Point_3 ab(-6.11, 18.55, 5.775);
  Point_3 ac(-6.11, 8.650001, 0);
  Point_3 ad(6.11, 8.650002, 0.000001);

  Polygon_2 pa;
  pa.push_back(rp);
  pa.push_back(rq);
  pa.push_back(rr);

  Polygon_2 pb;
  pb.push_back(aa);
  pb.push_back(ab);
  pb.push_back(ac);
  pb.push_back(ad);

  list<Polygon_with_holes_2> result;
  list<Polygon_with_holes_2>::const_iterator it;

  CGAL::do_intersect(pa, pb);
  // CGAL::intersection(pa, pb, std::back_inserter(result));
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did nothing wrong in your code, it's the function `do_intersect()` that requires functors that are not in the projection_traits. You need to construct "real" polygon_2 from your projections, and then call `do_intersect`on them.

```cpp
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel  Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<Kernel>                              Polygon_2;
typedef CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<Kernel>                 Gt;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<Gt>                                  Polygon_pr_2;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_with_holes_2<Gt>                       Polygon_with_holes_2;
typedef Gt::Point_2                                          Point_3;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Point_3 rp(1.840203021427314, 11.442402094914751, 1.6289004237251579);
  Point_3 rq(-1.3754475586433301, 7.159592255512721, -0.8694054147780097);
  Point_3 rr(5.879661577210586, 9.559327916542575, 0.530440182558408);

  Point_3 aa(6.11, 18.550001, 5.775);
  Point_3 ab(-6.11, 18.55, 5.775);
  Point_3 ac(-6.11, 8.650001, 0);
  Point_3 ad(6.11, 8.650002, 0.000001);

  Polygon_pr_2 pra;
  pra.push_back(rp);
  pra.push_back(rq);
  pra.push_back(rr);

  Polygon_pr_2 prb;
  prb.push_back(aa);
  prb.push_back(ab);
  prb.push_back(ac);
  prb.push_back(ad);

  Polygon_2 pa;
  for(const auto& p : pra)
  {
    pa.push_back(Kernel::Point_2(p.x(), p.y()));
  }

  Polygon_2 pb;
  for(const auto& p : prb)
  {
    pb.push_back(Kernel::Point_2(p.x(), p.y()));
  }
  list<Polygon_with_holes_2> result;
  list<Polygon_with_holes_2>::const_iterator it;

  CGAL::do_intersect(pa, pb);
  // CGAL::intersection(pa, pb, std::back_inserter(result));
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: 1. Thanks for your time!
2. Which parts of the doc should I have read to not ask this question?
3. Your code sample doesn't work here I needed to unfold that for loop as apparently pra and prb doesn't provide a necessary bit.
4. From '2D Triangulation > 4.3 Geometric Traits' docs projections should lift the result back into place. I don't see where this could would compute Z coordinates to put the polygons back in place.
5. And how is this different than just omitting Z coordinates for my polygon instead of using projection trait, as it does not rotate but simply removez Z as well.

Comment: 2. The requirements for do_intersect() are missing form the doc, there were no chance you could have found it by youtrself, I guess.
3.It worked for me, but probably only with CGAL 5.0, for c++11 loops.
4

Comment: 4. It wouldn't, but as you are not using a triangulation, there is nothing to lift up.
5.If you have to build a 2d polygon, then the traits become useless. Using operations that are permitted by the traits, it is faster and less memory consuming.

Comment: My ultimate goal was to get the intersection of two Polygon_3 which are on the same plane (but not on xy, yz, xz). I'm doing this already by rotating the said polyongs by an angle X, doing the 2D boolean operation and then rotate the result by angle -X. But code is getting hairy and less tested. OR. 5) Actually I can use Tri3 vs Tri3 intersection of CGAL (which I got working in 3D space) and apply it on each face (Tri3) of the said Polygon 3's that'll work for sure but I doubt if it is efficient.

Comment: You can use https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Principal_component_analysis/group__PkgPrincipalComponentAnalysisDLLSF3.html#gad39edb9f84ea2c280317e6c6c6146911 to detect the plane containing your polygones, and then https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Plane__3.html#a24c55e9e8c0250c70f377cba0d66f330 to project your polygones on the plane. Then you can create a polygon_2 from the resulting points and call do_intersect()

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into those.